# CSS flex centered columns with element wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My goal here is to have these 3 elements on the same line with vertical centering. I don't want to use a inner div to achieve this layout.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
div * {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>header 1</h1>
  <h2>header 2</h2>
  <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I have experimented adding a `flex-wrap`, `align-items: start;` and `flex-shrink`. I also tried setting the width of the elements individually. None of these have put the elements on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flex-direction: column won't work to keep them in the same line. Use row (default)...

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
div * {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>header 1</h1>
  <h2>header 2</h2>
  <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```

[responsive demo](https://codeply.com/p/WCrfmMACfU)

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want or have I understood you wrong?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}
div * {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>header 1</h1>
  <h2>header 2</h2>
  <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```